# In TexStudio, when you compile an included Chapter, does the whole document gets compiled?

Tags: chapters, compiling, texstudio

Suppose in my document (book), I have a Chapter

\include{chapter_1}

and I edit Chapter 1 only within the Chapter 1 tab

Afterwards I hit the green arrow to compile/run

Does the whole document get compiled or just that one file?

Comment: unrelated to texstudio you can add `\includeonly{chapter_1}` to the preamble of your document to just process chapter1 , but if the final result is showing the full document, the full document was processed, it can not splice in fragments of pdfs to an existing document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the whole thing will get compiled which is slow.

You can include (in the top of your main tex file)

```
\includeonly{
chapter_1,
}
```

This will make it compile chapter 1 only.